# How to change product price in multishipping quote?

Tags: magento-1.9, quote, multishipping, product-prices

I am working in one module where I need to set my custom price replacing product price in multishipping quote. Price changed successfully on cart page and onepage checkout, but in multhishipping it takes default product price, how can I change price in multishipping?

Please help.